# JSON/CLOB Group by running for a long time

Tags: sql, json, oracle, clob

I have a JSON/CLOB field that I'm able to extract data from, but whenever I try to summarize or count data it runs forever without returning anything. Below is an example:

```
SELECT 
    FOUND_IN_MART,
    JSON_VALUE(JSON_DATA, '$.name.moduleCodesSelected[0]')  as mod_1,
    JSON_VALUE(JSON_DATA, '$.name.moduleCodesSelected[1]')  as mod_2,
    JSON_VALUE(JSON_DATA, '$.name.moduleCodesSelected[2]')  as mod_3,
    COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY
    FOUND_IN_MART,JSON_VALUE(JSON_DATA, '$.vdps.contactchannel'),
    JSON_VALUE(JSON_DATA, '$.cssr.moduleCodesSelected[0]') ,
    JSON_VALUE(JSON_DATA, '$.cssr.moduleCodesSelected[1]'), 
    JSON_VALUE(JSON_DATA, '$.cssr.moduleCodesSelected[2]') ;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by other columns than in select list. All columns which are not aggregated should be a part of `group by` clause. In this case `select` list contains columns:

```
JSON_VALUE(JSON_DATA, '$.name.moduleCodesSelected[0]')
```

while in `group by`:

```
JSON_VALUE(JSON_DATA, '$.cssr.moduleCodesSelected[0]')
```

Notice: `name` versus `cssr`. Here is the [dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5824312926d96b93aa8f3794ea2571f9) which shows the problem (first query is corrected version, second is yours).

You can also rewrite this query to make json transformation only once, like here:

```
select found_in_mart, mod_1, mod_2, mod_3, count(*)
  from (
    select found_in_mart, 
           json_value(json_data, '$.vdps.contactchannel') contact,
           json_value(...) as mod_1,  -- choose cssr or name 
           json_value(...) as mod_2,
           json_value(...) as mod_3
      from t)
  group by found_in_mart, contact, mod_1, mod_2, mod_3
```

If this won't help please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54951464/edit) your question and show sample data, something which allows us to replicate wrong behavior. preferably in the form of [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18).